# Problema con método y clases en Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de gestión de inventarios, el cual tiene un inicio de sesión que me está generando muchos problemas. He probado distintas maneras pero siempre tengo un error. Como ya no sé qué más hacer, recurro a esta página en busca de ayuda.

El error que me da en estos momentos es:

> 'mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing
> format-parameters; Python 'stringvar' cannot be converted to a MySQL
> type'

También me ha tirado errores como que el cursor no estaba definido, que las variables no existían, etc. El tema es que en otros métodos he hecho las cosas de la misma manera que en este, pero este es el único que arroja problemas

El código que me está generando problemas es el siguiente:

Esa sería la parte gráfica del programa

```
 def __init__(self, window):
    self.wind = window
    self.wind.geometry("400x400")
    self.wind.title('Registro e inicio de sesión')
    

    frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Inicio de sesión', height = 200)
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 50, padx = 50)
    
    userverify = StringVar()
    passwordverify = StringVar()
    
    # Usuario
    Label(frame, text = 'Usuario: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 10)
    self.user = Entry(frame, textvariable = userverify)
    self.user.focus()
    self.user.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    # Contraseña
    Label(frame, text = 'Contraseña: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = 5)
    self.password = Entry(frame, textvariable = passwordverify)
    self.password.focus()
    self.password.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    # Botones
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Iniciar sesión', command = self.iniciar_sesion(userverify, passwordverify)).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E, pady = 5)
```

Y ahí ejecuto el inicio de sesión

```
def iniciar_sesion (self, userverify, passwordverify):
    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    
   
    query = "SELECT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE nombreuser = %s and contraseña = %s"
    parametros =  (userverify, passwordverify)
    cursor.execute(query, parametros)
    cnx.commit()
    resultado = cursor.fetchall()
    if resultado != None:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Inicio de sesión correcta")
        #self.wind.destroy()
        Product()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(message="Usuario o contraseña incorrecta")
```

Todo esto está dentro de una clase llamada Login

Comment: Bienvenido LV17 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Mencionas un error, te sugiero que agregues a tu pregunta cual es este error o errores en particular.

Comment: Que librerías estas usando? Tienes alguna restricción? Yo intentaría de no reinventar la rueda, y usar algun framework como Django que ya tiene motor de bases de datos, sistema de usuarios, etc para hacer una aplicación más agil.

Comment: Estoy usando mysql.connector. El tema es que es un proyecto para el colegio, no sé mucho sobre python y se entrega el mes que viene. No tengo demasiado tiempo como para cambiar todo. Más que nada porque esto es lo único que no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza esta línea, te debería funcionar:

```
 # Botones
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Iniciar sesión', command = self.iniciar_sesion(userverify.get(), passwordverify.get())).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E, pady = 5)
```

**StringVar()** declara una variable de control para Tkinter (un objeto). A MySQL solo le interesa el valor de la cadena (el usuario o la contraseña), el método **get()** te permite obtener ese valor.

Answer (score 0):

Al final, tu idea era la correcta, pero en otra parte del código.
Quedó así:

```
query = "SELECT contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE nombreuser = %s and contrasena = %s "
    parametros = (userverify.get(), passwordverify.get())
    cursor.execute(query, parametros)
```

Muchas gracias!